# distance between two points using public transport using Google API

Tags: c#, google-maps

Using the Google API, how can I get the distance between two points using public transport?

I was able to get time between two points (using public transport) but not the distance. Using car as option, I can get both distance and time.

Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double dist = GetDrivingDistanceInMiles("Cubbon Park, Kasturba Road, Bangalore, Karnataka 560001", "Majestic, Bangalore, Karnataka");

        Console.WriteLine("Distance is :: ");
        Console.WriteLine(dist);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static double GetDrivingDistanceInMiles(string origin, string destination)
    {
        string url = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" +
          origin + "&destinations=" + destination +
          "&mode=driving&language=en-EN&units=metric ";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responsereader = sreader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();

        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml(responsereader);


        if (xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("status")[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText == "OK")
        {
            XmlNodeList distance = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("distance");
            return Convert.ToDouble(distance[0].ChildNodes[1].InnerText.Replace(" km", ""));
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

This code gives me distance between two points by driving, but is there anyway to get distance when using public transport.

Comment: Not off topic. This is a valid question of the properties returned by a google-maps-api v3 method.

Comment: this is not offtopic. I wanted to know if i can find a way to get distance property.

Comment: Perhaps if you try rewording the question and complete it with your current code, it would be re-opened :(

Comment: thanks amenadiel. Done

Comment: is that .NET ? I don't recognize it.